~を～をする construction
I was watching a video of 参議院議員 speaking and noticed this construction used twice by two different people.
https://youtu.be/F2YHiMV8BcM?si=Dvy9tvSNGjgYcedk&t=379 6:19
その上で 改正後の子供・子育て支援法におきましては 保育に対する給付である 子供のための教育 保育 給付とは別に 乳児等通園支援の理由に対して乳児等のための支援給付という個人給付を創設をする ということを規定する というものでございます
and https://youtu.be/F2YHiMV8BcM?si=zn6spoiZy-zW1ZUC&t=621 10:21
「子供誰でも通園制度」の本格的実施の際には 実施主体である市町村による認可のもと 受け入れ態勢が整っている施設において実施することを予定をしていまして…
Am I correct in assuming this is interchangeable with ～を～する? I don't know if it's a conscious decision by them to speak like this or if these are just errors in speech, because it seems ungrammatical to me. If so, I am wondering why they wouldn't just use ～を～する.

You're correct, this "double を" is not part of the standard grammar. It's something said by mistake while reading a complicated sentence vocally. You should say either 個人給付の創設をする or 個人給付を創設する.

@naruto Thanks for your reply! You always give great answers.

Like naruto said, it's a "mistake" but it happens particularly often when politicians speak, and I feel like it's because of an semantic aim.
Basically, when one says をする instead of する the action sounds more deliberate/formal/professional.  E.g. if you say 親子で会話する it merely means the parents chat with the children (perhaps once, on mundane topics with mundane aims). If you say 親子での会話をする then it means more like "facilitate the communication between the parents and the child". It's more "significant".
I think this is why politicians tend to use をする a lot, and in the process they make these ”mistakes”. But IMO it's arguable if the double を are really a mistake, because it makes the sentence sound even more deliberate. For example this sounds a lot like a politician:「親子での会話を、促進をするという意味合いがあるので、この施設には貴重な役割というものがあるのであります」 and IMO 会話を、促進をするという would be a deliberate word choice instead of a mistake.
